# Formatting an external HDD stuck at 70%

Tags: external-hard-drive, format, smart

My external HDD which is a 250GB WD (powered by USB) seems to have problem.

Whenever I try to copy some files, it stuck while copying. I decided to format it. So I used windows tool and performed the format (not quickly) however at nearly 70% it stuck.

Then I decided to perform a low level format with [lowlevel](http://www.lowlevelformat.info/download.aspx). Again it stuck at 70%.

I endup that the HDD has bad sector. So is there any tool that mark the bad sectors and bypass them? It is not very reasonable to through 250GB because of some bad sectors.

P.S: I saw a similar [topic](https://superuser.com/questions/528018/external-1tb-hdd-is-stuck-in-raw-format) but there were no conclusion there either. The SMART data is

```
Attribute,         raw value, value, threshold, status
Read Error Rate,       50,     200,    51,        OK
Spin-Up Time,         3275,    154,    21,        OK
Start/Stop Count,     2729,     98,     0,        OK
Reallocated Sectors Count,0,    200,    140,      OK
Seek Error Rate,        0,      100,    51,       OK
Power-On Hours (POH),  1057,     99,     0,       OK
Spin Retry Count,       0,     100,     51,       OK
Recalibration Retries  ,0,     100,     51 ,      OK
Power Cycle Count,    1385,    99,      0,        OK
Power-off Retract Count, 425,   200,    0,        OK
Load /Unload Cycle Count,12974, 196,     0,       OK
Temperature,          43,       43,     0,        OK
Reallocation Event Count,0,    200,      0,       OK
Current Pending Sector Count,23,200,    0,      Degradation
Uncorrectable Sector Count, 0,  100,    0,        OK
UltraDMA CRC Error Count,6,   200,      0,        OK
Write Error Rate/Multi-Zone Error Rate,0,100,51,  OK
```

It seems that the most important thing is this line

```
Current Pending Sector Count,23,200,    0,      Degradation
```

Any idea on that?

Comment: That's strange. The drive doesn't look aged, and the non-quick format should succeed even in case of bad sectors (at worst the disk controller should simply reallocate them). One possible explanation (pure guessing) is a mechanical problem, with the heads that can no longer go past 70%. Try creating 2 partitions, the first one that occupies 80%, the second one 20%. Do not even try formating the first one, and try a non-quick format on the second one (if it succeeds then my guess is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you have some badblocks, you should backup your data and stop relying on disk, because usually it's the first sign that your disk is going to silicon heaven.

You may try to use `format /p:1 <yourdisk:>`, this will rewrite every sector of your disk with zero, which in some cases triggers HDD firmware to automatically reallocate bad blocks.

note: this procedure may take several hours so be prepared

I've always done this with `dd` command in linux, so I'm not 100% sure if it'll work with `format`. But I think it's worth a try. Good luck.

Comment: The OP stated that he used a "not quick" format, which is supposed to write the entire disk afaik. It's strange that he gets stucks at 70%, because as you said it should just trigger a reallocation of the pending sectors.

Answer (score 0):

> So I used windows tool and performed the format (not quickly) however
> at nearly 70% it stuck.
>
> Then I decided to perform a low level format with lowlevel. Again it
> stuck at 70%.

Both tools do about the same; write  zero filled sectors so it makes sense if one fails the other will too.

> I endup that the HDD has bad sector. So is there any tool that mark
> the bad sectors and bypass them? It is not very reasonable to through
> 250GB because of some bad sectors.

You're doing it. Normally a write to a pending sector forces the drive to re-evaluate the sector and if it reaches the conclusion it's "bad" it will reallocate the sector. These evaluations take time, can be even 20 seconds per sector. Since lowlevel accesses the disk using Windows API, Windows itself may attempt several times, each of the attempts taking 20 seconds each.

You can try some tool like Victoria for Windows but it seems to me the drive has a serious problem. You can have it run a surface scan but it can also run the drive's internal short and extended self diagnostic tests.

[image]

"Some bad sectors", potentially 23 is what we know *now*. There may yet undiscovered problematic sectors. Since the drive seems to have trouble reallocating, the spare sectors could be bad themselves for all we know.

Or even the system area of the drive where it keeps SMART logs etc. can contain bad sectors. Data recovery specialists run into this and using special hardware/software that provides firmware access and manipulation tools they stop the drive from reallocation attempts and updating SMART logs.

Also consider bad sectors may be indicative for more serious issues.

Anyway, the number of bad sectors you're willing to accept is arbitrary perhaps. **If this were my drive I'd replace it**.

Answer (score -2):

In this instance, I would make three suggestions.

1. Immediately back up your data on that drive. Immediately.
2. How much power does your drive use? A USB port only delivers 500 ma of power at 5 VDC and many drives need more power. If it needs more than 0.5A or 500 ma, then obtain a double-headed cable and power it from two USB ports to get all the power needed. I've seen quite a few users with erratic external; drive behavior which cleared up when they got enough power to the external drive.
3. More important, though, is the 30% unusable space. I would strongly suggest, once you've made sure you have adequate power to the drive, that you obtain the manufacturer's drive utility and use that to inspect the drive after making sure you have the current firmware for its controller. Here, for example, are links to Western Digital's Passport utilities http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=218&sid=171&lang=en as well as a wider list of utilities for drives http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?level1=6  if you did not buy the external drive from Western Digital. Other manufacturers have similar pages.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_sector should also be instructive here.
4. And, if the aforementioned utilities don't resolve it, well, return it to the manufacturer for warranty replacement, as Hardware Fails.

Comment: I don't think about power problems. I used for nearly 3 years with usb on different laptops and dekstops

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to check. Just find what the model number is, and then check its power consumption at the manufacturer's website. If it uses less than a total of 0.5A or 500ma at 5VDC, you're fine. If it uses more, well, then give it more and it may behave better.

Answer (score -2):

If you have not tried the following, give it a shot.

1. perform a disk defragmentation.
2. try to format the HDD from command prompt. ( format i:  ). "Helped me all the time".
3. try some bad sector repair tools from the following http://softadvice.informer.com/Bad_Sector_Repair_Tool.html